# Code analysis error using "match" as variable name (python 3.10, PyDev, Eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, analysis

I'm using
Eclipse 2022-03
PyDev 10.0.1
and I get code analysis error when I try to use "match" as variable name

Example:

```
s = 'one'
match s:
    case 'two':
        print(2)
    case 'one':
        print(1)
    case _:
        print('nothing')
        
match = {}
match.update({'a': 1})
# code analysis shows the following message: 
# Encountered "update" at line 11, column 7. Was expecting:     "." 
 
print(match)
```

the above code works fine (I use python 3.10), but I get error message in eclipse
(code analysis), which messes up the rest of the file's analysis.
I read that "match" is soft keyword and is ok to use it.
(it's also used a lot in existing code and this is a big problem to me right now)

How can I fix that?

I tried changing the pydev code analysis with pylint, but this doesn't seem possible,
because according to the pydev docs, the pylint will run after, not instead of the pydev analysis.
I can't find anything useful while searching on the internet, because "match" is generic word
and I find only topics not related to my problem. When I search in stackoverflow, I don't see this or similar problem with working solution.